# Selenium with Java - How to restart the test in same window where it leaves the page

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to run the test again in the same browser tab when it is completed where it leaves the page. Basically, my intention is to test the site on multiple languages that can be selected through a drop down.

Also, I use Browserstack to automate it.

The below listed code  will enable me to select next drop down item each time when test is completed.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='trigger']/div/paper-input/paper-input-container")).click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".style-scope.making-language-selector.iron-selected.x-scope.paper-item-0")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".style-scope.making-language-selector.iron-selected.x-scope.paper-item-0")).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN, Keys.ENTER);
```

I did not use any frameworks to implement it.
Thanks in advance,

Comment: Is clicking on Language opens new tab ?

Comment: Nope. It stays on the same page. Any idea what code to add at the end of the test ?

Comment: I think you should use test framework, eg TestNG, then you can perform some actions before all/each test case (for example prepare application in one tab) or group test in specific order

Comment: @user6696575 As kotoj suggested you can use any test framework either JUnit or TestNG. However, TestNG gives more flexibility to design, group, include and exclude particular tests.

Comment: I just implemented the framework. Thanks for your answers. What should I type after @After to run the same in this case?